# Layover in Warsaw. Will I be quarantined?

Tags: covid-19, poland, quarantine

I'm flying from Brussels to Tallinn on the 7th September in LOT. I have a 2.5 hours layover in Warsaw.

Is there a possibility that I will be quarantined in Warsaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Of course not**, since you're leaving again in 2.5 hours. AFAIK there's not a single country that prevents you from catching a connecting flight due to quarantine.

Also, per the government website ([LINK](https://www.gov.pl/web/coronavirus/travel)), those entering Poland from within the EU/Schengen don't have to quarantine.

Comment: To be clear, there are a few countries that won't let you transit under certain circumstances;  but in such cases, you usually won't be allowed to board your first flight.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, but in these cases the reason isn't that you have to be quarantined for (say) 2 weeks for the sake of it